# Is it possible to call a performSegueWithIdentifier from another class?

Tags: ios, class, uistoryboardsegue

**I just build a class to manage correctly my database and JSON request. The problem is that now, how can I perform the segue ?**

Here is my code 
In my view :

```
- (IBAction)loginClick:(id)sender
{
    NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"username=test&password=test"];
    [[DataManagement sharedManager] WebServiceLogin:post];
}
- (void) showTypeView
{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showTypeView" sender:nil];
}
```

In my class :

```
    -(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
    {
...
                switch ([[response valueForKey:@"success"] intValue])
                {
                    case 0:
                    {
                        NSLog(@"error: %@ error Description: %@", [response valueForKey:@"success"], [response valueForKey:@"error_message"]);
                        break;
                    }
                    case 1:
                    {
                        LoginViewController *showView = [LoginViewController new];
                        [showView showTypeView];
                        break;
                    }
                    default:
                        break;
                }
...
    }
```

When I launch, I have an error :
**

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Receiver (<LoginViewController: 0x165afd30>) has no segue with identifier 'showTypeView''
*** First throw call stack:
(0x2592e2eb 0x250fadff 0x29e2b037 0xe1819 0xdb64f 0x25f64de1 0x25f64d99 0x25f64e8d 0x25e261ef 0x25edf04f 0xa77cab 0xa7f835 0x25e171e3 0x258415f9 0x25e170cb 0x25e16f95 0x25e16e29 0x258f1257 0x258f0e47 0x258ef1af 0x25841bb9 0x258419ad 0x26abbaf9 0x29b2dfb5 0xe3ea9 0x254f4873)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

**

Comment: You can use a (custom) delegate (in `LoginViewController`) to tell the parent class that it needs to perform the segue.

Comment: How Can I do that :) I am a newbie. I am looking for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using segueWithIdentifier then you need to already have the segue built in Storyboard and labeled correctly as "showTypeView". Otherwise you should use a navigation controller to push a view controller or use self presentViewController to show a modal view controller.

EDIT:
Building off of Larme's comment, you can build a delegate like this:

```
// In your class.h file
@property (weak, nonatomic)id<SegueDelegate> delegate;

// In class.m file
LoginViewController *showView = [LoginViewController new];
self.delegate = showView;
[self.delegate segue];


// In LoginViewController.h
@protocol SegueDelegate
-(void)segue;
@end

@interface LoginViewController: UIViewController <SegueDelegate>
-(void)segue;
@end

// In LoginViewController.m
@implementation LoginViewController
-(void)segue
{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showTypeView" sender:nil];
}
@end
```

Comment: That's what I did, but it doesn't work. If I use the same function directly in the viewcontroller, it works.